# Avoid opening the same dialog each time the link is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a menu and each link in the menu is opened with a modal dialog. Im trying to avoid creating the same dialog everytime i click a link more than one time.

I have tried checking

```
if(outputHolder.hasClass('ui-dialog-content:visible')){return false;} 
 $("body").append(outputHolder);
 outputHolder.load($this.attr("href"), null, function() {      
 outputHolder.dialog(
```

otherwise it will display the dialog..

Any suggestions??

complete code

http://jsfiddle.net/6qgTr/5/

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the Search link in the fiddle. Is something supposed to happen?

Comment: so you are supposed to say you want different modal popups on each menu links? Fiddle is not working anymore

Comment: Im saying that every time i click search it creates a new dialog.. so im wondering how to avoid this behavior and make the dialog pops up just only 1 TIME when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want it so that only the first time the dialog is displayed the ajax call is made, but on subsequent clicks, the dialog is redisplayed without the ajax call being remade, correct?

If that is the case, I think you first have to get rid of the following code because it removes the elements for the dialog when it is closed. Without it the elements will remain, but be hidden.

```
close: function(event, ui) { $(this).remove(); }
```

You would also need to keep track of the dialog div elements so you can re-use them. You could use the `.data()` method for this.

```
function openDialog($dialogDiv) {
    $dialogDiv.dialog({
        // options, but not including 'close'
   });
}

function loadEmployeesShow(link) {
    var $link = $(link),
        $dialogDiv = $link.data('dialogDiv');
    if (!$dialogDiv) {
        console.log('creating new dialog');
        $dialogDiv = $('<div>');
        $link.data('dialogDiv', $dialogDiv);
        $dialogDiv.load($link.attr('href'), function() { openDialog($dialogDiv); });    
    } else {
        console.log('reusing existing dialog');
        openDialog($dialogDiv);
    }
};
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/6qgTr/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You should start by creating a div in your html code that will be used as the basis of the dialog instead of creating it on the fly. You then can open and close this same dialog instead of creating a new one each time.

Also keep all your JavaScript code separate from your HTML.

On your dialog settings the first option you have is `bgiframe: true` this is not a valid option for dialog.

Your not going to be able to load the dialog with data from `https://www.google.com.ar`

Quoting the [jQuery ajax page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

You would have to point to a script on your own server that would do what ever retrieving you need.

[I created a new fiddle with what I think you want.](http://jsfiddle.net/oumichaelm/6qgTr/8/)